# How to use metacity theme for my GTK application on Windows

Tags: c, gtk

My OS is Windows 7

I use minGW and GTK2

I have single GTK application written with C that looks like:

[image]

I changed GTK theme to MAC and got followed view:

[image]

My aim is to **how to activate metacity** for my application to make my main window borders to be rounded like:

[image]

Currently I have windows default view. I have `metacity-theme-1.xml` that I took from the MAC theme package and don't have idea how to use it.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not completely mistaken, on Windows, the "window decoration" is not handled by GTK. If you want to modify it for your application, you have to implement a platform-specific piece of code, which makes use of some Windows API.

Comment: I know that for Linux Env. - yes it is. Other graphic tools (not cross-platform) can handle it. Maybe I need provide (install) additional metacity themes for Windows, whos know

Comment: Yes, in Linux it works. For changing this kind of stuff in Windows, you need to work with some Windows API. Maybe (big maybe), GTK provides some abstraction layer for this - but I have never seen one.